# get image out of CDATA and description tag with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, rss

How do i get a image out of a CDATA and description tag?
Here is the XML code:

```
<description>
    <![CDATA[
        <img src='http://www.autowereld.com/imagesDB/100/311151018460_.jpg' border='0'                     bordercolor='black' style='float:left; margin-right: 8px;margin-bottom: 8px;'>
    ]]>

    Het is Subaru wat de klok slaat deze week. Na spyshots van de Subaru Legacy Touring,     gelekte foto’s van de productierijpe WRX en de officiële bekendmaking van de Legacy Concept is     het nu tijd voor de Crossover 7 Concept.
</description>
```

This is what i got:

```js
var img = $(element).find("description").text();
img = img.replace("<![CDATA[", "").replace("]]>", "");
console.log(img);
$("#img").append('<img src="' + img + '">');
```

Comment: The CDATA markers shouldn't appear in the text unless you are paring the XML incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you try to:

```
var img = $(element).find("description").text();
        img = img.replace("<![CDATA[", "").replace("]]>", "");
        console.log(img);
        $("#img").append(img); // <-- use only the var ing
```

to remove the CDATA and image tag out of the description tag :

```
var dsr = $(element).find("description").text();
dsr= dsr.substring(dsr.indexOf('>')+1, dsr.length);
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked! And how can i remove the CDATA and image tag out of the description tag?

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape `[ and ]` like,

```
img = img.replace("<!\[CDATA\[", "").replace("\]\]>", "");
```